# How to transpose the panel data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, transpose, melt

Consider the first data structure. I need to transpose it as in the second structure.

[image]

I tried df.melt and df.pivot_table, but did not work.

Comment: You need two steps, `melt`+`pivot`